# Vlfeat for Ipython

Tags: python, image-processing, ipython, jupyter, vlfeat

I've been trying to set up vlfeat library for Jupyter which comes with anaconda. 
I've installed from this https://anaconda.org/menpo/vlfeat but cant import the library in the notebook. Can someone Guide on how to set it up?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from cyvlfeat import sift
```

That should get the module loaded.

Comment: this does not load the module for me

Comment: @iratzhash (very late, but...) if that did not work for you, probably you did not install it correctly or it is not visible to the `jupyter` notebook. Remember that `conda` install packages under its own `PATH`.